(MLA/biblatex-mla) How to edit \printbibliography to have "Works Cited" be properly formatted?
I've reworked my question and finally narrowed down the problem.
So, what the problem seems to be is \printbibliography tries to have "Works Cited" flushed to the left, and I want this to be centered, and not bold.
However, this is because the command relies on the definition of section, and this is changed in my preamble when I redefine section to be equivalent to the format of a level one heading according to MLA standards
Is it possible to have "\printbibliography" be able to avoid using this definition of section? Is there a way to have it the way I want it to be? so that it's basically
{\centering Works Cited\par}  

Citations

\documentclass[
12pt,
letterpaper
]{article}

\usepackage[
    style=mla-new,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[
american
]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% Level 1 Heading: bold, flush left
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{*0}{*0}

 
%%% Final Settings
\RaggedRight
 
\addbibresource{references.bib}
 
\begin{document}
 
 
\section{Introduction}
John Locke, a prominent Enlightenment thinker, profoundly influenced modern political theory and practice. His ideas on natural rights, government by consent, and separation of powers have shaped democratic societies worldwide \autocite{locke1690}.
 
\clearpage 
\printbibliography
 
\end{document}

references.bib:
@book{locke1690,
  author    = {John Locke},
  title     = {Two Treatises of Government},
  year      = {1690},
  publisher = {Awnsham Churchill},
  address   = {London},
  edition   = {First Edition},
  series    = {Political Philosophy},
  note      = {A seminal work in the development of political theory, Locke's treatises lay the groundwork for modern democratic thought and theories of government. This edition is notable for its comprehensive exploration of the nature of political authority and the social contract.},
  url       = {https://archive.org/details/twotreatisesofgo00lock},
  keywords  = {Political Philosophy, Social Contract, Enlightenment},
  isbn      = {978-0-1234-5678-9}
}

Would greatly appreciate any help

You can use \defbibheading to customise the bibliography heading.
\documentclass[
12pt,
letterpaper
]{article}

\usepackage[
    style=mla-new,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[
american
]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% Level 1 Heading: bold, flush left
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{*0}{*0}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[Works Cited]{%
  \clearpage
  {\centering#1\par}}

\RaggedRight
 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
 
\begin{document}
\section*{Test}
Ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}.

\section{Introduction}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}.

 
\printbibliography
\end{document}


